# Symfony Add bootstrap form-control class

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8, I have created one registration form, I want to add bootstrap form-control class to both password and repeat password form fields.

```
$builder 
->add('name', TextType::class,array(
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control'
    )
))  
-> add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
    'type' => PasswordType::class,
    'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
));
```

Incase of 'name' field its working BUT for password fields the class is not adding.
How can I add 'form-control' class for password fields.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.  The first is to use [`options`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#options), which will pass the options down to each of the underlying fields:

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
    'type' => PasswordType::class,
    'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
    'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
    'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'))
));
```

You can also add the class in the [`first_options`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#first-options) and [`second_options`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#second-options) field, like so. This would be useful if you had options that were specific to each field or you wanted to override something from the main options.

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
    'type' => PasswordType::class,
    'first_options'  => array(
        'label' => 'Password',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
    ),
    'second_options'  => array(
        'label' => 'Password',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control-override')
    ),
    'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
));
```

Also, [as of Symfony 2.6](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme) it has has [built-in Bootstrap form theme support](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes) to where you shouldn't have to be adding these classes to all of your fields manually.

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Some guys from the Symfony development team, suggest that you should use the boostrap's classes directly in html ([here](https://youtu.be/MyGlUAvyIrs?t=661), if you want to see the suggestion). And the suggestion makes perfect sens to me, as Symfony is for backend development, and not frontend. So the ideal way of solving this is to create your two fields in the `Type` class, and when rendering the form, add something like:

```
{{ form_row(name, { attr: { 'class': 'form-control' } ) }}
{{ form_row(password, { attr: { 'class': 'form-control' } ) }}
{{ form_row(plainPassword, { attr: { 'class': 'form-control' } ) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in form themes for twig templates since [Symfony 2.x](https://symfony.com/doc/2.x/reference/configuration/twig.html#config-twig-form-themes).

For versions 4.x and up simply add one of the [available themes](https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/form/form_themes.html) in the `config/packages/twig.yml` file, like so:

```
twig:
    /* ... */
    form_themes: ['bootstrap_5_layout.html.twig']
    /* ... */
```