# How can I remove form-control class?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I need to remove the form-control class on an element of a form because it applies padding. This class is automatically added when creating the form.
And I don't want padding on any of these form lines...But how to do it ?
Here is my code :

Form : only the part of the form on which I don't want "form-control" class.

```
->add('progress', RangeType::class, [
                'label' => 'kpi.form.progress',
                'attr' => [
                    'min' => 0,
                    'max' => 100,
                ],
            ])
```

Twig :

```
{% for formTeamOKR in formCompanyOKR.teamOKRs %}
   {% for formKPI in formTeamOKR.KPIs %}
       {% if formKPI.vars.data.id == kpi.id %}
          {{ form_row(formKPI) }}
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to use this :
[How to prevent Twig from adding form-control class to the fields it generates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749240/how-to-prevent-twig-from-adding-form-control-class-to-the-fields-it-generates)

and this : [Symfony Add bootstrap form-control class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46346198/symfony-add-bootstrap-form-control-class)

and to add this in my twig :

```
{% set attr = {class: (attr.class|default(''))|trim} %}
```

just before :

```
{{ form_row(formKPI) }}
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is wrong with the first question you linked ? It's exactly what I'd answer to your question.

Comment: Did you try to create your own Form-Layout?

Comment: This does not technically answer the question but it seems to me that adding css that removes padding would be a lot easier.

Comment: Because I already tried with {% set attr ... %} and It doesn't work @AymDev

Comment: No, I didn't. I thought I'd find a easier solution@Yannick

Comment: really advanced: the only thing i can think of is "inline form overriding", https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-different-themes-to-child-forms this, but instead of using a complete form theme combine `_self´ with your original form_theme (multiple form themes: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#applying-multiple-themes-to-single-forms) plus a delicately overridden form row or widget to remove the classes via specific fragments defined (see  https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#form-fragment-naming second list point)

Comment: actually, the link to prevent form-control from being added assumes you to have your own form theme, but I assume you're very new to form theming and it didn't get applied at all. ... which is the challenge with form theming.

Comment: If you created the form theme from the first answer and didn't work, be sure to clear the caches. You cannot affect rendering of the `form_row` by overriding `attr` from outside, as you seem to be doing. Adding `'class' => 'p-0'` to the `attr` array, as suggested above, is probably the easiest solution.